# Possibility of running git repo from Azure blob storage

Tags: c#, git, azure-blob-storage, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I'm trying to build a version control service using git and backed by (Azure) blob storage. My intention is to create a bare repo on the local file system, then migrate this directory/file structure into blob storage (which I have done).

The next part involves working with this repo to make commits, fetch the latest version, *etc.*.

I naïvely hoped that if I put the entire contents of the bare repo into blob storage, I could then use the shared access signature / URI as the remote path for the repo. However, when using [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-clone) and calling...

```
Repository.Clone(sharedAccessUri, localPathForClone);
```

... an exception tells me...

> Unsupported URL protocol

So either my naïve assumption (that I could simply place the repo directory structure into blob storage and call it from a URL) is wrong, or...  might it be that libgit2sharp only supports HTTP***S***? (At the moment I'm developing locally and the shared access URI is HTTP.) As they say in their README...

> we currently lack proper documentation

If it's not possible to use blob storage as the remote repo then I suppose I could create it locally, zip it, store this archive as a blob, and then later retrieve this archive, unzip, then clone that.

So, is it possible to run the remote repo directly from Azure blob storage?

Comment: For in-house business reasons. The end users are not developers but people who work on a standardised file-type in a third-party application. I'm trying to wrap git functionality into a combination of API and application plugin.

Comment: Azure Blob Storage is not appropriate for storing "live" or unpacked git repos because locking ("leasing") in Azure Blob Storage does not work exactrly the same as normal local filesystem locks, which means that even if you are able to make it work for a single user you won't be able to make it work for concurrent users. Why can't you just run the official git server on a local on-prem server?

Comment: My understanding is that bare repos don't have locking.

Comment: Is the "standardized file type" text or binary? Because if it's binary, Git is **entirely** the wrong tool to begin with and you should be looking at using something better suited for binary file versioning. Even if it's text, if the concern is that people will have trouble learning and operating Git, then some other, simpler version control system like Subversion will still be infinitely superior and have a richer, more stable feature set than whatever in-house tool you develop. My gut says you are reinventing the wheel in a really dangerous way here.

Comment: For context, the goal is to allow freelancers using a commonly-used application - which encourages plugins - to submit their work. I’m building an open-source service/plugin which handles versioning. According to your comments I should tell anyone who wants to use this that they should instead subscribe to "GitHub, GitLab, Azure DevOps, and so on", and then instruct all freelancers - some of whom may only ever do one job on this platform - that they should learn how to use git before they start the job. Or how about I wrap that functionality in a service/plugin so they don’t have to?

Comment: Azure Blob Storage is not a git server / repository that you can clone from. "_If it's not possible to use blob storage as the remote repo then I suppose I could create it locally, zip it, store this archive as a blob, and then later retrieve this archive, unzip, then clone that._" that sounds like it would possibly be too problematic and won't work properly.